# Elasticsearch: aggregate by similar substrings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index of documents with only one property each. The records are like

```
Products Sport
Products Health
Products Home
Questions CSS
Questions HTML
Questions JS
```

There are a lot of documents an a lot of duplicates. The question is can I somehow group them by "similarity" (in any sense) and add the "common part" to each document, so I will have something like

```
Products Sport         Products
Products Health        Products
Products Home          Products
Questions CSS          Questions
Questions HTML         Questions
Questions JS           Questions
```

It's just for analysis purposes, so it can be very inaccurate, but should be quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is _update_by_query. Something like this for each category to add a field named category and set it's value using scripts

```
POST index/_update_by_query? conflicts=proceed
{
  "script": {
   "source": "ctx._source['category']='Products'",
    "lang": "painless"
 },
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "Products"
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative:
If you are looking to just perform group by for results, then you can use the exists query clause to get the documents of certain type and then perform aggregations on them with out updating the documents

Comment: But how can I know that I should search for "Products"? What I'm looking for is some kind of clustering algorithm. Something like k-means by string norm or substring norm.

Comment: If you don't know what fields are in your documents, You could do a match all query to get every document then enumerate the fields first. Obviously you will have to use a high-level client and the scroll API then

Comment: Also I think Kibana with x-pack might have something along this lines already if you want to check that out

Comment: Of course, I can create something similar to kmeans in memory with scroll API, but seems like elasticsearch has inside norm indexes, that's why I think there is possibility to do this with some script call inside elastic itself. So, basically I want out-of-the-box solution (more or less) or at least something quicker than one of the kmeans modifications algorithm.